# Find the general solution of PDE non homogenous

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of PDE:
$$ u_{xx}+u=6y, where, u=u(x,y) $$

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I was trying to use the canonical forms, and it didn't quite work

Comment: Why was this upvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an inhomogeneous PDE, the solution is the sum of the general solution of the associated homogeneous PDE and one particular solution. The associated homogeneous PDE is
$$u_{xx}+u=0$$
and its general solution is
$$u(x,y)=c_1(y) \cos(x)+c_2(y) \sin(x) .$$
By inspection, one can see that $6 y$ is a particular solution.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you find the particular solution?

Comment: @Areedd I've made a mistake, the particular solution should be $6y$.

Comment: so basically the particular solution would just be f(x,y)?

Comment: @Areedd Not always. But if $f$ is a first order polynomial in x, it is.